# Best way to get a minecraft servers status - query, stream_socket...?

Tags: php, sockets, tcp, stream, status

some time ago I used query to check the status of a minecraft server via. php, but I wasn´t so happy with the results. Sometimes it just took more than 10 seconds or didn´t even got the status although the mc server was up and the webserver within the same data center.

Which method do you think would work most stable and with a good performance: query, stream_stocket or something else ?

Should I run the test every 30 seconds via. a cronjob or just cache the results for 30 secs '?

Comment: Personally, I use `socket_sendto()` and `socket_readfrom()`, since you don't need to be connected to the socket to send/receive the request. You could try using memcached to store the result for x seconds, then when the data expires store it again.

Comment: @BenFortune Hi, I never worked mit socket_sendto() and socket_readfrom() would you be so kind and show me how do you do it ? Do you think that it works this way more stable and with a better performance, than with query or stream_stocket_client ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a PHP file with this code and run periodically to store the status.

```
<?php
/**
 * @author Kristaps Karlsons <kristaps.karlsons@gmail.com>
 * Licensed under MPL 1.1
 */

function mc_status($host,$port='25565') {
    $timeInit = microtime();
    // TODO: implement a way to store data (memcached or MySQL?) - please don't overload target server
    $fp = fsockopen($host,$port,$errno,$errstr,$timeout=10);
    if(!$fp) die($errstr.$errno);
    else {
        fputs($fp, "\xFE"); // xFE - get information about server
        $response = '';

        while(!feof($fp)) $response .= fgets($fp);
        fclose($fp);
        $timeEnd = microtime();

        $response = str_replace("\x00", "", $response); // remove NULL

        //$response = explode("\xFF", $response); // xFF - data start (old version, prior to 1.0?)
        $response = explode("\xFF\x16", $response); // data start

        $response = $response[1]; // chop off all before xFF (could be done with regex actually)

        //echo(dechex(ord($response[0])));
        $response = explode("\xA7", $response); // xA7 - delimiter

        $timeDiff = $timeEnd-$timeInit;
        $response[] = $timeDiff < 0 ? 0 : $timeDiff;
    }
    return $response;
}

$data = mc_status('mc.exs.lv','25592'); // even better - don't use hostname but provide IP instead (DNS lookup is a waste)

print_r($data); // [0] - motd, [1] - online, [2] - slots, [3] - time of request (in microseconds - use this to present latency information)
```

Credits: skakri (https://gist.github.com/skakri/2134554)

Comment: thanks, but the question was about which way would be the fastest (lowest resource usage) not how. ;)

Comment: @user2693017 this script is pretty fast. here took 1 second.